# regular expression allowing numbers starting with option plus sign and spaces and minus sign in between numbers

Tags: regex

I am looking for regular expression that allows

```
starting with optional '+'
numbers more than 7 length
can contain '-' in between numbers
can contain ' ' between numbers
```

So far I have

```
+?[0-9-_]
```

the '+?' allows optional '+' only once.

```
0-9
```

allows 0 to 9 numbers

'-' and '_' allows '-' and spaces in between numbers

But my regular expression is not working as expected. Any help will be appreciated

**Edited**

```
Valid strings

+92214678320
902123045
0017806801276
4891243
```

Comment: Can you provide some valid strings?

Comment: @hwnd Updated my questions with valid string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes you should make**

- Escape the `+` at the start
- Move `-` to the begeining of character class

Regex can be

```
^\+?[-0-9 _]{7,}$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/23)

Comment: This doesn't allow spaces as stated

Comment: @hwnd i misread space with underscore corrected in answer. Thank you.

Comment: He asks for numbers more than 7. Does not seem this would work. It matches 12345-6 as well

Comment: @Khanna111GauravKhanna yeah It wont work with that. But i think by *numbers more than 7 length* op meant the entire string

Answer (score 2):

i assume by "numbers more than 7 length" you mean a string that contains at least 7 digits, as in a phone number:

```
^\+?(\d[\s\-_]?){7,}$
```